# Amazon RDS and SQL Session State

Tags: sql-database, session-state, amazon-web-services

I am setting up an environment with the databases stored on Amazon RDS. I am running into a problem with using SQL Session State. I get the YSOD with this error:

```
Parser Error Message: Synonym 'Applications' refers to an invalid object.

Source Error: 


Line 354:    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="mssql" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
Line 355:      <providers>
Line 356:        <add name="mssql" type=" Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="private" />
Line 357:      </providers>
Line 358:    </sessionState>
```

Which I have seen before. I have solved this by re-running the sql boost scripts on the session database. BUT, on RDS, I dont seem to be able to run this script. Even as the SA I dont have permission to alter Synonyms or add SPROCs. Has anyone else run into this and come up with a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Sitecore you are using but if you are on 8.2 I strongly suggest you looking into AWS's ElasticCache using the Sitecore ASP.NET Session State Provider for Redis.

Comment: I can't test this, so I won't put it as an answer at this point. But essentially, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447931/81631 suggests you create the Session DB locally and then use the SQLAzureMW tool to migrate it to RDS.  Alternatively you could edit your scripts, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082855/81631

Comment: The problem had to do with the sql boost script. This causes session to make heavy use of the tempdb. I did not figure out how to grant read write to the tempdb in RDS